# Why does this function return None?

Tags: python, python-2.x

My function always returns `None`, what is going on here?

```
Az= [5,4,25.2,685.8,435,2,8,89.3,3,794]
new = []

def azimuth(a,b,c):
 if c == list:
    for i in c:
       if i > a and i < b:
           new.append(i)
           return new

d=azimuth(10,300,Az)
print d
```

In addition, if someone know how can i extract the location of these numbers to a different list it will be really helpful.

Comment: to know the location of the a item inside a list you can use `Az.index(item)` that give you the position of the first occurrence of item inside of your list, and if you want the positions of all, you can use `enumerate(Az)` that return a list of tuples `(position,item)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if c == list:` is checking if `c` is a `type` i.e a `list` also if `if i > a and i < b:` never evaluates to `True`  you will never reach your return statement therefore by default `return None` as all python functions do that don't specify a return value, I imagine you want something like:

```
Az = [5,4,25.2,685.8,435,2,8,89.3,3,794]

def azimuth(a,b,c):
  new = []
  if isinstance(c ,list):
     for i in c:
        if  a < i < b:
           new.append(i)
  return new # return outside the loop unless you only want the first
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
def azimuth(a, b, c):
    if isinstance(c, list):
        return [i for i in c if a < i < b]
    return [] # if  c is not a list return empty list
```

If you want the index too use `enumerate`:

```
def azimuth(a, b, c):
    if isinstance(c, list):
        return [(ind,i) for i, ind in enumerate(c) if a < i < b]
    return []
```

If you want them separately:

```
def azimuth(a,b,c):
  inds, new = [], []
  if isinstance(c ,list):
     for ind, i in enumerate(c):
        if  a < i < b:
           new.append(i)
           inds.append(ind)
  return new,inds #
```

Then unpack:

```
new, inds = azimuth(10, 300, Az)
```

Comment: you could also make other simplification `i > a and i < b` to `a < i < b`

Comment: @Copperfield, True, thanks simplified chained comparison is nicer

Comment: that's great, i did run the first code (before the simplified). 
After running in with 'Az' as the list, it it returns only 1 variable in the new list- 25.2, but it was also suppose to put inside 89.3. ( i did a and b as 10 and 300)

append can insert only 1 variable to the 'new' list?

@PadraicCunningham

Comment: `print(azimuth(10, 300, Az))` returns  `[25.2, 89.3]` which is correct, there are the only two values in the range

Comment: that is the problem, i don't understand why it returns only 1 value, i switched them and then i get a return of only 89.3, as it appends only the 1st variable that fits the conditions.

maybe it has to do with my editor, i know the solution should be clear and that both values should return 

@PadraicCunningham

Comment: @nadav_n, You can see here https://repl.it/B9jV/0 that is does exactly what it should

Comment: i'm such a noob, no wonder people are killing my rep, thanks man. @PadraicCunningham

Answer (score 2):

The first `if` in the function is checking whether `c` is the built in type `list`.

```
>>> list
<type 'list'>
```

Thus the check won't be true and `return new` will never be reached.
The function will return the default value `None` in this case.

To check whether something is a list, use `isinstance`:

```
>>> c = [1,2,3]
>>> c == list
False
>>> isinstance(c, list)
True
```